# How to make this POST request with different objects?

Tags: json, swift, post

## Overview:

I am trying to make a POST request, which I have done before with only strings. This time, I have a few variables, being: `String`, `Int`, and `Bool`.

## Error:

`Cannot assign value of type [String : Any] to type Data`

## Line causing the error:

`request.httpBody = paramToSend`

## Question:

- How to convert a `Dictionary` into `Data` ?

## Complete Code:

```
func sendComplimentAPI (message: String, recipient: Int, isPublic: Bool) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://complimentsapi.herokuapp.com/compliments/send/")
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
    request.addValue("\(preferences.object(forKey: "token") as! String)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    
    let paramToSend = ["message":message,"recipient":recipient,"is_public":isPublic] as [String : Any] 
    request.httpBody = paramToSend
    
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        
        guard let _:Data = data else {return}
        let json:Any?
        do{json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])}
        catch {return}
        
        guard let server_response = json as? NSDictionary else {return}
        
        if let session_data = server_response["id"] as? String {
            
            print("worked")
           //do something
            /*DispatchQueue.main.async (
                execute:
            )*/
        } else {
            print("error")
        }
    })
    
    task.resume()
    
}
```

EDIT:

I have tried this new code and it is still not posting to the server. I am attaching what I changed and also writing what the console shows for the two prints I have it do.

```
let paramToSend = ["message":writeTextField.text!,"recipient":1,"is_public":isPrivate] as [String : Any] //messageString + recipientString + isPublicString
            
            do {
                var serialized = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: paramToSend, options: .prettyPrinted)
                print(serialized)
                request.httpBody = serialized
                print(request.httpBody)
            } catch {
                print("found a problem")
            }
```

The console returns (for serialized and then the HTTP body):
113 bytes
Optional(113 bytes)

Is that optional causing the problem? How do I fix it?

Comment: It tells you to convert a dictionary into Data.

Comment: @ElTomato how do I do that?

Comment: @ElTomato I have tried multiple codes, and it still is not working when I get to the part of putting it in the HTTP body

Comment: @LeviK Just a small suggestion, once you find an error, isolate the line and let the question be specific to that line / problem

Comment: @user1046037 thank you, sorry I am new to all of this still. I added a comment to your solution, hopefully you can still help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To convert `Dictionary` to `Data`, use `JSONSerialization.data`:

## Solution:

`JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: paramToSend, options: .prettyPrinted)`

## Check the request:

- Print the request and see if it matches your expectation

## Reading the response:

```
//Check if there is any error (check if error != nil)

//Examine the response
let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode
let statusCodeDescription = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.localizedString(forStatusCode: httpResponse.statusCode)

//Check Data
if let data = data {
    let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this, but it still isn't working. Here is what I did, and nothing is posting to the backend:

`let paramToSend = ["message":message,"recipient":recipient,"is_public":isPublic] as [String : Any]
        
        do {
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: paramToSend, options: .prettyPrinted)
        } catch {
            print("found a problem")
        }`

Comment: Has the compilation error been solved ? Now is it a runtime problem that you don't get the output you expected ?

Comment: Print the request and see if it is what you expected.

Comment: I added an updated section on the post with the printed requests, hopefully you can tell me how to fix it based on the response

Comment: We need to see the output of the print statement. So paste the output of that print statement or check it if it is what is expected.

Comment: i did put the result of the print statement - it just returns Optional(63 bytes) I don't know if it doesn't actually show the body because it is encoded or if that is an actual problem. Something doesn't seem right though. However, if I check it at a break point it does contain the correct parameters, just the console does not show it from the print statement

Comment: There are 2 things here: request and response. First print the request and that should be readable. The response would be data that you can convert to string. Please do some searching. If request isn’t correct responses wouldn’t be correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173253/discussion-between-user1046037-and-levi-k).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to add a simple additional header to get the whole thing to work.

```
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

This is probably why it was not understanding the dictionary I was sending it